# Calling derived class constructor from base class

Tags: c++, polymorphism

given this code, (I use different code with constructors, destructors, virtuals, etc.), how would one implement A::createChild which adds a pointer to either B or C

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

class A {
    void createChild(std::vector<A *>);
};

void A::createChild(std::vector<A *>) {
    //What code goes here?
}

class B : A {};

class C : A {};

int main() {
    std::vector<A *> ptrs;
    ptrs.push_back(new B);
    ptrs.push_back(new C);
    ptrs[0]->createChild(ptrs); //Should add a new class of B to ptrs
    ptrs[1]->createChild(ptrs); //Should add a new class of C to ptrs
    assert(typeid(ptrs[2])==typeid(ptrs[0]);
    assert(typeid(ptrs[3])==typeid(ptrs[1]);
}
```

Comment: What's the relation between `A` and `B` or `C`?

Comment: Fixed. B and C are children of A

Comment: @NathanOliver you're right. I had misread it.

Comment: By they way you are using it it looks like it should be a virtual function.  You would implement it in each of the derived classes.

Comment: @user3117152 Sure you don't want `public` inheritance? Don't post bogus code but a real problem please. A template function `createChild()` might help to get what you want.

Comment: I implemented a `virtual A* createChild() =0` in my code. It worked great, much preferable to templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a template function to achieve that:

```
class A {
    template<typename Derived>
    void createChild(std::vector<A *>);
};

template<typename Derived>
void A::createChild(std::vector<A *> v) {
    v.push_back(new Derived);
}
```